# Missing foreign keys for Prestashop 1.6?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, prestashop, release

I figured out that Prestashop doesn't have foreign keys constraints. I found [this issue](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-7286) and I want to know if foreign keys will be adopted in next versions.

Anybody knows something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not such thing like 'missing foreign keys' because there aren't any foreign keys on PS and won't be developed on next version (PS 1.7)

On [this link](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/480580-want-to-know-more-about-17/page-2) to official forum, you can see the answer from a contributor who says that PS 1.7 Database will not have any foreign key.